# POST with json handling and Fast Android Networking

Tags: java, android, json

I'm sending some data with post that the server needs to check.
It returns a JSON object like this:

```
{"login":"true","error":"false"}
```

I want to check the value of `"login"`.
This is my code concerning this task:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String passw = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            pDialog.setMessage("Caricamento ...");
            showDialog();

                AndroidNetworking.post(AppConfig.URL_LOGIN)
                        .addHeaders("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .addHeaders("Authorization", "Token token=cazzodigomma")
                        .addHeaders("Accept", "application/json")
                        .addBodyParameter("email", email)
                        .addBodyParameter("password", passw)
                        .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
                        .build()
                        .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {

                                             @Override
                                             public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                                 hideDialog();
                                                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                 //"Va tutto bene :D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                 Log.d(TAG, "JSON: " + response);
                                                 JSONObject jsobj = new JSONObject();
                                                 try {
                                                     String login_json = jsobj.getString("login");

                                                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                                 }
                                                 if ("true".equals(login_json)) {
                                                     Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                     startActivity(intent);
                                                     finish();
                                                 }


                                             }

                                             @Override
                                             public void onError(ANError error) {
                                                 // handle error
                                                 hideDialog();
                                                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                         "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                             }
                                         }
                        );
        }
```

I guess the problem is in:

```
try {
     String login_json = jsobj.getString("login");

   } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
                             }
```

With problem I mean that:

1. if `login_json` is inside `try { }` I'm unable to use it in my IF
2. if `login_json` is outside `try { }` Android Studio gives me an Unandled Exception error.

Comment: It would help if you told us what the problem was. It looks like you are declaring `String login_json` in a differen scope than `onResponse`, so you can't access it outside of the `try-catch`. To fix, you could declare `login_json` outside of the try catch, and set it's value inside the try-catch.

Comment: Indent your code properly

Comment: if i put login_json outside the try catch Android Studio gives me Unandled Exception error, that's why i put it where it is. @nbokmans

Comment: Well that indicates there is something else wrong. The scope of the `login_json` is the `try-catch` block. You can't access that variable from the scope of the `onResponse` block - inner scopes can access variables outside it, but not the other way around

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/jCdGfZE.png for more information on scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the String from the Json object in response, so change

```
String login_json = jsobj.getString("login");
```

to

```
String login_json = response.getString("login");
```

Answer (score -2):

It was very simple. All I had to do was moving:

```
if ("true".equals(login_json)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

inside the `try { }`

```
@Override
                                             public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                                 hideDialog();
                                                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                 //"Va tutto bene :D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                 Log.d(TAG, "JSON: " + response);
                                                 JSONObject jsobj = new JSONObject();

                                                 try {
                                                     String login_json = response.getString("login");
                                                     if ("true".equals(login_json)) {
                                                         Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                         startActivity(intent);
                                                         finish();
                                                     }


                                                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                                 }



                                             }
```

However hank you for your answears and comments!

Comment: That's not the solution. The solution is what @Deepesh Choudhary posted.